# VBA Loop Through drop down, copy range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet named "Invoice Temp", invoice temp has a drop down on L4. 
Modifying this drop down updates cells in range A1: J54 of "Invoice Temp"

What I'm trying to do, is get VBA to scroll through the drop down list in L4, and for each value, copy range A1:J54 into a new work book and rename the sheet after the L4 value, and save it under folder: c:/folder a/

^ thats big picture. I've worked out how to get it to loop through and copy a single cell, but i seem to be having a problem copying the range.

Column K has the data validation for L4.

Thanks for the help!

here is what I got:

```
Sub trial()
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long
Set dataSheet = Sheets("Invoice")



   Dim curSheetName As String
   curSheetName = LefdataSheet.Cells(i, "K"), 24)

    Call AddSheet(curSheetName)

    Set trgSheet = Sheets(targetSheetName)


 'Which cell has data validation
  Set dvCell = Worksheets("Invoice").Range("L4")
 'Determine where validation comes from
  Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)
   i = 1
 'Begin our loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value



dataSheet.Range("prototemp").Copy
trgSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
trgSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
trgSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
trgSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
i = i + 1


Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub

Sub AddSheet(sheetName As String)

'Remove sheet if one already exist
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(sheetName).Delete
Err.Clear
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add sheet with designated name
Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
End Sub
```

Comment: In your loop, you set `dvCell = c.Value`, but then never use `dvCell`.  What's the loop supposed to do? It's *always* going to copy your named range "prototemp", no matter the `c` value.

Comment: Its supposed to loop through all the names in the drop down, and for each name, create a new workbook, with the range a1:j54 from invoice temp, with values and formatting. Naming the sheet with the corresponding value from the drop down.