# Loop through range select drop down

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro for the below steps but I am new to macros and could use your help.

I have a list of 10 lines starting at cell G11 in a sheet called "TABLE"and each one has a validation drop down (TRUE or FALSE). Following is what I would like to do.

1. Before the macro starts I want all of them to be set to FALSE.
2. Then I would like it to start with cell G11 and select TRUE from the drop down. The entire workbook is based off of this, so once it's set to TRUE there will be some calculations, then I want to take the results from the "SECURITIZATION" page and paste it in a sheet called "FINAL".
3. After this I would like to go to the "TABLE" sheet again, switch cell G11 from TRUE to FALSE, and go to cell G12 and select TRUE from the drop down and paste the results from the "SECURITIZATION" page below the results from G11.

I went through this macro but it selects from the drop down in the same cell not a list. 
[VBA Loop Through drop down, copy range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990820/vba-loop-through-drop-down-copy-range)

this is what i have so far

```
Sub SpitValues()

Dim dvCell As Range 
Dim inputRange As Range 
Dim c As Range 
Dim i As Long 


 'Which cell has data validation
Set dvCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G11") 
 'Determine where validation comes from
Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1) 


i = 1 
 'Begin our loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
For Each c In inputRange 
    dvCell = c.Value 

    Worksheets("SECURITIZATION").Cells(i, "A1").Value = Worksheets("SECURITIZATION").Range("G30").Value 
    i = i + 1 
Next c 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As written this question is way to broad to really be answered without having somone write your code base for you. If you show us what you have tried and where you are stuck with a clear and specific issue, we can help a lot more easily.

Comment: i just edited that, let me know if that helps.

Comment: That does help. Thank you. However the description of what you need and your code do seemingly different things. Which do you need?

Comment: I need the description, i would like the code to loop through cells G2-G11 and select from drop down to TRUE and then copy paste data then in the same cell select FALSE and then go to the next cell and select TRUE from drop down. All of them should be FALSE to start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot. It's based on the description. It needs editing for your specific copy | paste needs, which you can see in the notes.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SpitValues()

Dim wsTable As Worksheet
Set wsTable = Worksheets("Table")

Dim wsSecuritization As Worksheet
Set wsSecuritization = Worksheets("Securitization")

Dim wsFinal As Worksheet
Set wsFinal = Worksheets("Final")

With wsTable

    .Range("G11").Resize(10, 1).Value = "FALSE"

    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In .Range("G11").Resize(10, 1)

        rCell.Value = "TRUE"

        'DoEvents
         Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:10") 'wait for 10 seconds.

        'adjust this to whatever is need for copy | paste operation
        'I didn't see exact requirements for this so I just copy A1 each time below the last used row in column A
        wsFinal.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = wsSecuritization.Range("A1").Value

        rCell.Value = "FALSE"

    Next

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU this helps, how do i make the worksheet pause to calculate. Right now the macro copies and pastes the same value. It doesn't wait for the sheet to refresh and then copy paste

Comment: @user2521517 - see my edit as one way to do it. Another way could be to turn off automatic calculations and a `wsSecuritization.Calculate`. However, I have not found that to be reliable all the time.

Comment: @user2521517 - considering marking as answered so others know going forward